# Do...While not looping

Tags: java, do-while

I am having trouble with the `while` statement in java.  Here is my code (I am very new to this)...

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ElecticBillLab6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int accountNumber;
    int customerName;
    int oldMeterReading;
    int newMeterReading;
    int usage;
    double charge = 0;
    String name;
    String lastName;
    String response;
    final double baseCharge = 5.00;
    int yes = 1;
    int no = 2;
    boolean YesResponse;

    Scanner keyBoard = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {

        System.out.print("Customer's first Name? ");
        name = keyBoard.next();
        System.out.print("Customer last name?");
        lastName = keyBoard.next();
        System.out.print("Enter customer account number ");
        accountNumber = keyBoard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter old meter reading ");
        oldMeterReading = keyBoard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter new meter reading ");
        newMeterReading = keyBoard.nextInt();

        usage = (newMeterReading - oldMeterReading);

        if (usage < 301) {
            charge = 5.00;

        } else if (usage < 1001) {
            charge = (5.00 + (.03 * (usage - 300)));
        } else if (usage > 1000) {
            charge = (35.00 + ((usage - 1000) * .02));
        }

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("$,###.00");
        System.out.println("PECO ENERGY");
        System.out.println("Customer Account Number " + accountNumber);
        System.out.println("Name on Account " + name + lastName);
        System.out.println("Last Month Meter Reading: " + oldMeterReading);
        System.out.println("This Month Meter Reading: " + newMeterReading);
        System.out.println("Current Usage : " + usage);
        System.out.println("Your current month charges are "
                + (df.format(charge)));

        System.out
                .println("Do you want to enter another customer's meter reading?");
        System.out.print("Enter 1 for yes or 2 for no.");
        response = keyBoard.next();

    } while (response == "1");

}
}
```

The program does it once and does not loop correctly.  What is wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't `response == "1"` be `response.equals("1")`?

Answer (score 5):

You can't compare strings with ==.

Use

```
while(response.equals("1"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
response.equals("1")
```

`==` applied to Strings only returns `true` if it's the same object.

Answer (score 3):

This `response == "1"` is not how to compare `String`s in Java.

You actually want to use `response.equals("1")` instead, which will compare the contents of the two `String`s which each other and not there memory locations.